# Bash Cut, Sed, or Trim?

Tags: bash

I need to run a program and echo the final result, and save that in a variable. I currently have

```
myvar="(`echo 34 | ./prog | cut -d "." -f2`)"
```

The problem is the entire string is being shown. For example I see

```
34 hello the result is: 343
```

All I need is to save `343` in a variable. The reason I passed `34` is because I want to pass `34` when I run. I'm unable to save `343`. When I echo the variable, the entire variable is being shown on the screen...

Comment: `./prog` is not compiling anything. It is running `prog`. And that line should get you a string of `(<output from pipeline>)` in `myvar`.

Comment: that's true. I meant to run the program and pass 34. I compiled it earlier in the script. All I want is to save the end result in a variable.

Comment: What you have is doing that but with extra wrapping `()` around the returned value. What are you actually seeing in `myvar` after you run that line? Are you sure `prog` is working as intended?

Comment: What is the output of prog script

Comment: Try `./prog | awk '{print $NF}' `

Comment: Well, there are no dots in `34 hello the result is: 343`.  Does that follow a dot in the output of `prog`?

Comment: change `cut -d "."` to `cut -d ":"`

Answer (score 3):

Using *any* external tool -- `cut`, `sed`, etc -- is silly; bash can do this much more efficiently built-in:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^- must be /bin/bash for <<< to work; if /bin/sh, then myvar=$(echo 34 | ./prog)

myvar="$(./prog <<<34)"  # capture the full output of running ./prog with 34 on its stdin
myvar=${myvar##*: }      # delete everything up to and including the last ": "
echo "$myvar"            # show your results
```

See:

- [The bash-hackers page on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).
- [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) ("How do I do string manipulations in bash?")
- [BashFAQ #73](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) ("How do I use parameter expansion?")
- [The bash man page section on parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: If `/bin/sh`, use a here doc instead of piping the output of `echo`.

Comment: @chepner, indeed, that works too, but it's harder to describe on one line. :)

Comment: Now you're just being lazy :)